# How to fix 'Cannot POST /index.html' in Nginx, Express and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, react-router

I'm setting up my MERN project on my production server and whilst
making sure you can manually type in URL (such as `myproject.com/dashboard`) I added the following line to the `server` section of my Nginx configuration file `try_files $uri /index.html;` to allow this(as stated by the react-router training [page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory)). This has now caused the following response when trying to login `Cannot POST /index.html`.

If I remove the line all calls to the api work(i can login again) but I cannot enter url manually.

I've tried moving the `try_files` line to the top of the `server` section incase the server section is sensitive to this.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name myproject.com;
    root /home/forge/myproject.com/client/build;
    ...
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    ...
}
```

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use( express.static( `${__dirname}/client/build` ) );

app.use('/api/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/api/playlists', playlistRouter);


app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/client/build/index.html`);
});
```

I expect to be able to login(make calls to my api) and enter URLs manually to my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your configuration is not valid. In your config if requested file does not exists you are sending the file `index.html` no matter what. Will never call proxy.

Since your server has `/api` prefix configure that on your nginx server like this. So request starts with `/api` will be proxy to your backend server.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name myproject.com;
  root /home/forge/myproject.com/client/build;

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }

}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. And your explanation makes sense!